# Robustness of non-context-free proof against trivial manipulation

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, context-free

First, we state here a theorem that is well-known in computability theory:

> $L=\{xx\mid x\in\Sigma^*\}\notin CFL$ for every fixed $|\Sigma|\geq2$

And, the standard proof is using *pumping lemma*. At first sight, we rarely face the language $L$ exactly as defined above in a broader theoretical research. Instead, what might be more frequent is $$L'=\{\text{some-simple-manipulation}(x)x\mid x\in\Sigma^*\}$$ Perhaps, those simple manipulation are necessary for **unambiguous encoding**. For example, symbol doubling, prefix, postfix, etc. Those are quite frequent and unavoidable.

Now, the question is: **Can the above theorem still hold under these simple manipulations**?

**Symbol doubling** (as commented below) is a good starter, if one feels the question too broad.

**Or even worse**, there may be **some simple manipulation** that push $L$ down to CFL again.

Comment: Unless you specify the *simple manipulations*, the question will be hard to answer. Does reverse count, for example? For other manipulations, I would guess that standard closure properties would show that the modified languages are still not context-free.

Comment: Take symbol doubling as a starter, $001011$ indicates $011$ (the *second* in each pair terminates the current string)

Comment: Note that PDA is only **one-direction** less from being **Turing-complete**.

Comment: I don't understand what symbol doubling is. Could you please explain more?

Comment: @xskxzr I guess it means duplicating each symbol of the alphabet, e.g. $x=abcde$ to $x'=aabbccddee$.

Comment: @Yuval: That should be pumping lemma rather than some closure property. Closure property seems to fall short to a weak class like CFL in combination to some simple manipulation.

Comment: I believe closure properties are more appropriate for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $\left\{x^{\mathrm{R}}x\mid x\in\Sigma^*\right\}$ is context free, where $x^{\mathrm{R}}$ means the reverse of $x$.

> Or even worse, there may be some simple manipulation that push $L$ down to CFL again.

So if you consider reversing as a simple manipulation, the answer is indeed yes.

Comment: I just realize that symbol doubling like in my question can still be **pumped** to contradiction.